# Enormous amount of connections stuck in CLOSE_WAIT state with Varnish

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, varnish

I'm getting some kind of weird problem with varnish, an enormous amount of connections are stuck in `CLOSE_WAIT` state, just like if varnish wasn't closing connections.

This leads me think that the kernel is waiting for varnish to close the connections, considering this, it could be either a bug in varnish or the kernel from my point of view.

Though, before digging deeper into varnish code, I'd like to have your point of view guys, and know if this kind of symptoms could be caused by any other parameters ?

Obviously, if you ever experienced this problem and have the solution, it would be even more helpful.

FYI:

```
# netstat -pan|grep varnish|awk '/tcp/ {print $6}'|sort|uniq -c
  35902 CLOSE_WAIT
  12148 ESTABLISHED
      3 LISTEN
```

Comment: It is a bug in the application. Not the kernel. The kernel is waiti for the application to close the connection, having already received a close from the peer.

Comment: @EJP Unless the kernel doesn't notify the process that it has received FIN.

Comment: Come off it. A kernel that didn't do that would fail QA. *Nothing* would work. It's a bug in the application. Period.

Answer (score 2):

You should inspect whether they are in client ⇄ varnish side or varnish ⇄ backend, probably they would be in the backend side, at least that's my case.

According to [Connections to backend not closing](https://www.varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2010-February/018197.html):

> This is actually per design, varnish keeps backend connections around
>   if they look like they can be reused, and only revisits them when it
>   tries to reuse them, so they may linger for quite a while before
>   varnish discovers they have been closed by the backend.
>
> Apart from the socket hanging around, it is harmless.

I would also check if your backends are closing connections unnecessarily, keepalive (if you are able to use it) is of great help. And finally, check the output of `varnishstat -1 |grep backend` to see if varnish is able to reuse backend connections (`backend_reuse`) and if it has noticed that they are closed (`backend_toolate`). The values should be so `backend_reuse` + `backend_toolate` ≅ `backend_recycle`.